# each function Jquery throwing error in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-10

I have written a piece of code to search an entire document and find data . To do that I am using each function. Now this work perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox but in IE10 implementation of each function in JqueryFramework.js, it throws error saying "Unable to get property 'replace' of undefined or null reference ".

Here is the code I have written

```
$(xml).find('interface').each(function () {
        oldxml=$(this);
    if ($(this).find('Param').html()!=null) { 
     // alert($(this).find('Param').html());
        if ($(this).find('Param').html().indexOf("Tunnel0")>-1) {

            $(oldxml).find('tunnel').each(function () {
               // alert($(oldxml).html());
                if ($(this).find('Param').text().length >0 ) {
                    //code
                   // alert($(oldxml).text());
                    interfaceArray[interfaceArray.length]=$(this).find('Param').text().trim();
                    //alert($(this).find('Param').text().trim());

                }
                if ($(this).find('IPAddressHostName').text().length >0 ) {
                    //code
                    peerAddressArray=$(this).find('IPAddressHostName').text().trim();

                }
            });

        }else if ($(this).find('Param').html().indexOf("Tunnel1")>-1) {
             $(oldxml).find('tunnel').each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('Param').text().length >0 ) {
                    //code
                    interfaceArray[interfaceArray.length]=$(this).find('Param').text().trim();
                }
                if ($(this).find('IPAddressHostName').text().length >0 ) {
                    //code
                    peerAddressArray=$(this).find('IPAddressHostName').text().trim();
                }
            });
        }
        }
        });
```

Comment: There needs to be more code than this. I can't find any occurrence of 'replace', which is what throws an error.
Are you sure the error is in this file?

Comment: implementation of each() is inside jqueryframwework.js . and the error is thrown from jqeuryframework.js.

Comment: I am having the same problem.. I am using jQuery 1.8

Comment: HI people , I found the problem. IE 10 does not support .html() api from JQuery.

Comment: Anil plese look for different functions which are not supported by IE 10